# How do I set my `base_uri` when using the HTTParty gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, httparty

I am creating a small Rails at that consumes an external geolocations API. It should take a string (address) and return the coordinates. I am not sure how to set the base URI with the HTTParty gem. The documentation of the API says requests can be sent to the endpoint

`GET https://eu1.locationiq.com/v1/search.php?key=YOUR_PRIVATE_TOKEN&q=SEARCH_STRING&format=json`

How do I go about setting the token and the search string in my class method? Here is the code I have so far.

locationiq_api.rb

````
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "https://eu1.locationiq.com/v1/search.php?key=pk.29313e52bff0240b650bb0573332121e&q=SEARCH_STRING&format=json"

  attr_accessor :street

  def find_coordinates(street)
    self.class.get("/locations", query: { q: street })
  end

  def handle_error
    if find_coordinates.code.to_i = 200
      find_coordinates.parsed_response
    else
      raise "Couldn't connect to LocationIQ Api"
    end
  end
end```

locations controller:

```class LocationsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_location, only: [:show, :destroy, :edit, :update]

def new
  @search = []
  # returns an array of hashes
  @search = locationiq_api.new.find_coordinates(params[:q])['results'] unless params[:q].nil?
end

def create
  @location = Location.new(location_params)
  if @location.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'      
  end
end

private

  def location_params
    params.require(:location).permit(:place_name, :coordinate)
  end

  def find_location
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  end
end```
````

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```rb
class LocationIqApi
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "https://eu1.locationiq.com/v1/search.php"

  def initialize(api_key, format = "json")
    @options = { key: api_key, format: format }
  end

  def find_coordinates(street)
    self.class.get("/locations", query: @options.merge({ q: street }))
  end

  def handle_error
    if find_coordinates.code.to_i = 200
      find_coordinates.parsed_response
    else
      raise "Couldn't connect to LocationIQ Api"
    end
  end
end
```

Then when you want to use it, you'll need to create a new instance with your key:

```rb
@search = LocationIqApi.new(YOUR_API_KEY_HERE).find_coordinates(params[:q])
```

Comment: That's giving me an error when I try to load `http://localhost:3000/locations/new` `NameError in LocationsController#new
uninitialized constant LocationsController::LocationIqApi`

Comment: Where is locationiq_api.rb (as in, which folder inside Rails)? It might be because of the capitalisation, so that means autoloading isn't kicking in - try calling the class `LocationiqApi` instead?

Comment: it's app/services. I've changed it to LocationIqApi as per your example but still get this error.

Comment: do i need to require the class method or anything like that? can't seem to put my finger on it

Comment: You might need to explicitly require the file, unless you add app/services to your autoload paths (although depending on your Rails version this might not be needed): `config.autoload_paths += [ Rails.root.join("app", "services") ]`.

If you change it to `LocationIqApi`, then the file will need to be named `location_iq_api.rb` rather than `locationiq_api.rb` - the filename is how Rails knows that constant should be defined in there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - changing the file names worked. Well, at least I'm getting a different error message now ;) `TypeError in Locations#new, no implicit conversion of String into Intege`

Comment: Usually that means you're trying to access an array like a hash or vice versa - I'd check the exact object that's being returned from your `#find_coordinates` method.